# Golang cannot read PNG from S3

Tags: image, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to read png files from AWS S3, which return `[]byte`.

However, I cannot read png from `bytes.NewReader()`. Here's my code right now

```
config := aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String(region),
}
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&config))

svc := s3.New(sess)

s3Output, err := svc.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
})

if err != nil {
    return make([]byte, 0), err
}

buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
buf.ReadFrom(s3Output.Body)

imgReader := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())
_, format, err := image.DecodeConfig(imgReader )
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
fmt.Println(format)
img, err := png.Decode(imgReader)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

The format returns `png` but an error `png: invalid format: not a PNG file`

I tried using file and it succeed

```
file, err := os.Open(ImageFile)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// decode jpeg into image.Image
img, err := png.Decode(file)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
file.Close()
```

How can I work around this?

**UPDATE**

Here's the output of `s3Output`

```
{
  AcceptRanges: "bytes",
  Body: buffer(0xc04220e040),
  ContentLength: 102104,
  ContentType: "image/png",
  ETag: "\"d1b5490e26ddd6259cd5d17fa3c4dc6b\"",
  LastModified: 2018-08-16 09:30:35 +0000 UTC,
  Metadata: {

  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue it is related to the bytes that you are decoding. AWS S3 stores the image in file or base64 encoded data which one is it. Post the output of `s3Output`

Comment: OK! I updated my question

Comment: Have you uploaded the image by yourself on aws S3. What you have provided seems like an address to the buffer created where image is saved. List the objects inside the bucket where you have uploaded the image.

Comment: Yep! I uploaded the S3 through the AWS console without altering the metadata etc. And mind if I ask what's the relevancy of the objects inside my bucket for solving the answer? It's just a precaution :) if there's a relevancy, I'll update the question to list the objects

Comment: No its ok Its not needed. Have your tried aws s3 download manager for golang sdk

Comment: It seems that if I use s3Output.Body I can decode it. You can see my answer. I just don't know why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I don't know why but if I use `s3Output.Body` instead of using the bytes, I got the right result.</s>

```
config := aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String(region),
}
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&config))

svc := s3.New(sess)

s3Output, err := svc.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
})
img, err := png.Decode(s3Output.Body)
```

You can explain why this happens and I'll happily mark your answer as the correct answer :)

It turns out that the reader would get altered in `image.DecodeConfig`

So if I use

```
imgFormat := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())
imgReader := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())
_, format, err := image.DecodeConfig(imgFormat)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
fmt.Println(format)
img, err := png.Decode(imgReader)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
fmt.Println(img)
return nil, nil
```

it won't throw any error. I'll stick with this right now but if there's any better method, please feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use AWS S3 download manager which will let you to download the image directly with metadata and location of the image uploaded on aws s3 as

```
buff := &aws.WriteAtBuffer{}
s3dl := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)
_, err := s3dl.Download(buff, &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
})

if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Could not download from S3: %v", err)
}
```

Using the `s3Output.Body` will give you the output because it is already in bytes with uploaded file content. So you need to create a buffer using the image after converting it into bytes. The function `png.Decode` works on io.Reader as:

```
func Decode(r io.Reader) (image.Image, error)
```

> Decode reads a PNG image from r and returns it as an image.Image. The
>   type of Image returned depends on the PNG contents.

Check [this example](https://golang.org/src/image/png/example_test.go) where Base64 code is converted to image using `png.Decode`.

AWS S3 provided special download manager to do the operations of downloading the file from the bucket directly. For more information [Check AWS S3 Basic bucket operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-basic-bucket-operations.html)

Comment: How do you use png.Decode with `buff`? the type of `buff` is `*aws.WriteAtBuffer`

Comment: @KendrickKesley the response coming from the server implements `io.Reader` which is why you can use it inside `png.Decode()`. But if you are using your code to upload the image file from the `os` using `os.Open()`. then you should convert it into bytes which will implement `io.Reader`. That's why buffer is used to convert image file into bytes.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you said, but I'm not uploading my image from the server. I just want to build a function to read a png, which will be converted to jpg later. And the png would come from S3. But I think I know what's the problem now and It's related to the `DecodeConfig` function. I'll update my answer

Comment: @KendrickKesley ok let me tell you a thing. I have Base64 code now how can I convert it into image. Try to to do that convert a base64 code to an image. you will get to know. Check this function for png decode https://golang.org/pkg/image/png/#Decode. And see what is the argument to  the function.

Comment: From my question, the file is already in bytes. and I converted it to a reader. Btw I updated my answer and it seems it's working now. Thank you!

Comment: @KendrickKesley yes you are right but if you see the definition of `func NewReader(b []byte) *Reader`.  NewReader returns a new Reader reading from b. So again it returns Reader by converting bytes.